# Drawing DOM elements: mouse events get confused by background elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm building a DOM drawing app. These fiddle's are identical:

http://jsfiddle.net/tomsoderlund/4d29S/ (without grid - works)

http://jsfiddle.net/tomsoderlund/J46Z8/ (with grid - doesn't work)

except for the background grid, e.g.:

```
<div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 99.5%;"></div>
<div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 0.5%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
```

The background grid messes up the mouse events, as you will notice when you start drawing on the canvas.

How can I improve this code? Ideally, I'd like the drawing code to mimic the JQuery UI *Resizable* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

May be drawing divs is conflict with grid divs...so change ur HTML elements like

**html**

```
<div id="content" class="weld-element-container" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
  <div class="grid_outer">
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 0%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="right: 0%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline y" style="top: 0%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline y" style="bottom: 0%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 0.5%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 99.5%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 0.5%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 8.83%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 91.17%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 8.83%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 17.17%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 82.83%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 17.17%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 25.5%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 74.5%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 25.5%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 33.83%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 66.17%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 33.83%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 42.17%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 57.83%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 42.17%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 50.5%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 49.5%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 50.5%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 58.83%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 41.17%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 58.83%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 67.17%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 32.83%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 67.17%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 75.5%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 24.5%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 75.5%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 83.83%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 16.17%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 83.83%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 92.17%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-gridline x" style="left: 7.829999999999998%;"></div>
    <div class="weld-grid-column" style="left: 92.17%; width: 7.33%;"></div>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
.grid_outer {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index: 1;
        top:0px;
        left:1px;
    }

#content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2; /*Should be more than `.grid_outer`*/
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/J46Z8/4/)

Comment: Ah, now I see. `.grid_outer` cannot be a child of `#content`. Do you know why?